# SuppressMessage for a specific class/type only

Tags: c#, warnings, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to suppress "Missing XML comment" (`CS1591`) but only for a specific class. The class in my case is `System.Windows.DependencyProperty`. I want the warnings to appear for every other occasion. Adding `CS1591` to `<NoWarn>` won't work as this will simply ignore all occurrences.

What I tried was to create a `GlobalSuppressions.cs` at my project's root and adding the following line to it:

```cs
[assembly: SuppressMessage( "Missing XML comment", "CS1591", Justification = "No need for DependencyProperty docs.", Scope = "type", Target = "~T:System.Windows.DependencyProperty" )]
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `#pragma warning disable CS1591` right above your class definition and `#pragma warning restore CS1591` at the end.

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-pragma-warning

Comment: The problem is that the `DependencyProperty` is defined in `System.Windows` and is not my own code.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm confused. what does your full warning look like? I'm not sure how you are getting a compiler warning for a reference that's already been compiled. I assumed you had some class with public properties of type `DependencyPropery` and you just wanted to ignore warnings from that class.